# Developable 3-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Is there a classification of the equivalent of a "developable surface" in $\mathbb{R}^4$?
Analogous to: planes, cylinders, cones, and tangent developables in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
**Edit:** Here I am imagining "developing" a 3-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ into
$\mathbb{R}^3$. (Apologies for the earlier misleading version!)

I would appreciate any suggestions for source materials here.  My only source 
(**Edit:** now evidently misleading)
is one page (p.342) in Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen (*Geometry and the Imagination*), in which they say: in $\mathbb{R}^4$

> there are surfaces that are isometric to the Euclidean plane in the small but are not ruled.

But now I see from the comments that this must mean a two-dimensional surface embedded
in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is not exactly what I seek.

A precise definition of *developable 3-manifold* in $\mathbb{R}^d$ would also be much appreciated.
Thanks for pointers!

Comment: Isn't the definition of a developable surface that the Gauss curvature is zero?  That's independent of the ambient space.  

Comment: "Flat" tori cut out by the equations $x_1^2+y_1^2=a^2$, $x_2^2+y_2^2=b^2$ are zero Gauss curvature surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which are not ruled as they are compact.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus

Comment: @Ryan: Pardon my ignorance, but what does it mean for the Gauss curvature to be zero in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Would this mean all sectional curvatures are zero?

Comment: @Joseph: I'm thinking through the lens of the Theorema Egregium.  The surface has a Riemann metric, so it has a curvature tensor and a Gauss curvature. It's a surface (2-manifold) so it only has one sectional curvature, which coincides with the Gauss curvature.   It appears we use slightly different terminology.  

Comment: @Ryan & jc: OK, I see now where the confusion lies (of course with me).  I want to "develop" a 3-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I can see I am misusing terminology, in particular the word "surface," which I was thinking as 3-dimensional rather than 2-dimensional. Sorry to trigger a tutorial!

Comment: I edited in an attempt to clarify.  Apologies!

Comment: Hmm, in light of the new edit, the quote from "Geometry and the Imagination", and my answer below seem now redundant :P

Comment: Do you know the etymology of "developable surface" for surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$?  I'm curious why such surfaces got the adjective "developable" attached to them.  Presumably this was from before the Theorema Egregium ?    I'm a little at a loss as to what you'd like "developable" to mean for co-dimension one submanifolds. 

Comment: @Ryan Budney: Perhaps this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_%28differential_geometry%29 ?

Comment: My understanding is that "to develop in the plane" is akin to the phrase, "to roll out on the plane."

Comment: @Ryan: Maybe this helps: One can unfold the tesseract into 3D: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28polyhedron%29 . I want to "roll" a 3-manifold onto a 3-flat, analogous to rolling a 2-manifold onto a 2-flat.

Comment: see  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8023/when-is-a-riemannian-metric-equivalent-to-the-flat-metric-on-mathbb-rn/8026#8026  

apparently you need the Ricci curvature of your 3-manifold to vanish.

Comment: @Will: Thanks for the pointer, that is quite clarifying. So now I seek an inventory of the 3-manifolds whose Ricci curvature vanishes.

Comment: It's not so much abstract 3-manifolds as, say, orientable ones in $\mathbb R^4.$ For your general concerns you would enjoy "Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry" by John A. Thorpe. He does everything for hypersurfaces of Euclidean space that one ordinarily sees for abstract manifolds. I admit, he does not get to the full curvature tensor. But you do need more information than you have on the second fundamental form, etc. As usual, if Rob Kusner has some time, a discussion in person is worth any number of MO answers.

Answer (score 6):

This is really just an amplification of Deane's answer.  As he points out, it is indeed true that a flat submanifold $M^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ whose second fundamental form is nonvanishing is canonically ruled by $(n{-}1)$-planes.  However, just being ruled in this way does not imply that the submanifold is flat.  For example, the hyperboloid of one sheet in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is ruled by lines (in two ways, in fact), and it is not flat.

The explicit description of the local flat hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is, of course, classical, and it goes like this:  Start with a regular curve $p:(a,b)\to S^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, choose a smooth function $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$, and solve the differential equation $dq = g\ dp$, yielding a smooth curve $q:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Now consider the set $M$, consisting of the vectors of the form $q(t) + v$ where $v$ satisfies $v\cdot p(t) = v\cdot p'(t) = 0$.  This will be a (ruled) hypersurface most places, and, where it is, the induced metric will be flat.  Note that this says that such hypersurfaces depend on $n$ functions of 1 variable (the first $n{-}1$ of them come from the curve $p$ and one more comes from the function $g$).

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I completely forgot that ruled does not imply flat.

Comment: I tried to understand why $M$ is flat. Hopefully the following helps someone. $T_{q(t) + v}M = \mathrm{span}\{q'(t), w : w \cdot p(t) = w \cdot p'(t) = 0\}.$ Since $w \cdot p(t) = 0$ and $q'(t) \cdot p(t) = g p'(t) \cdot p(t) = 0$, and $|p(t)| = 1$, the curve $p(t)$ parameterizes the image of the Gauss map. Hence the differentials $DU_{q(t) + v}$ of the Gauss map $U : M \to S^n, U(q(t) + v) := p(t)$ are $0$ (when restricted to $T_{q(t) + v}M$). I.e. the second fundamental form of $M$ is trivial. So the Gauss Equation implies the Riemann curvature tensor of $M$ is trivial, so $M$ is flat.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I explain below why a flat hypersurface implies ruled, but the converse is not true. See Robert Bryant's answer for a more precise explanation.

It is a theorem that any 2-dimensional open surface in $R^3$ that has zero Gauss curvature everywhere (and therefore is a flat 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold) is a ruled surface (i.e., is foliated by straight line segments). Such surfaces apparently are called developable surfaces.

I have not bothered to check the details but I am betting that everything generalizes in a straightforward manner to an $n$-dimensional hypersurface in $R^{n+1}$. Such a hypersurface has a flat Riemannian metric if and only if the sectional curvature vanishes on all tangent 2-planes. But the sectional curvature of any tangent 2-plane is equal to the determinant of the restriction of the second fundamental form at that point to the 2-plane. Therefore, the hypersurface is flat if and only if the rank of the second fundamental form is at most 1. The proof that a 2-dimensional surface is ruled probably extends to show that any flat hypersurface in higher dimensions is foliated by codimension 2 planes. So these could be called developable hypersurfaces. In other words, a hypersurface is flat if and only if it consists of a 1-parameter family of codimension 2 planes.

ADDED: I have confirmed that the above is right. In particular, any neighborhood of a point where the second fundamental form is not identically zero can be foliated uniquely into codimension 2 planes. This is a nice and rather easy exercise in the local geometry of a hypersurface in Euclidean space using the Frobenius theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed thoroughly in section 42 of "Differential Geometry of Two Dimensional Surfaces in Hyperspace" by E.B. Wilson and C.L.E Moore. The entire book "Proceedings of the American Academy of Arts and Sciences" (volume 52) is available from Google Books or from the [archive](http://www.archive.org/details/proceedingsofame52amer).

---

I think it makes sense to define a developable hypersurface as the envelope of a one parameter family of hyperplanes, this way it seems clear that in codimension 1 there is a foliation by hyperplanes. (See exercise 4.63 in the notes "Intorduction to Differential Geometry" by Robbin and Salamon)

Comment: A link to read the article online is here: http://www.archive.org/stream/proceedingsofame52amer#page/n277/mode/2up

Comment: @Gjergji: Thanks, this is new to me and will be useful. I apologize for changing the question out from under your feet, so to speak!

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, and it only addresses the compact case.

If you take *developable* to have the original sense of the word (provided by jc's Wikipedia link above), a developable 3-manifold in $\mathbb R^4$ would be (in the language of geometrization) a *Euclidean* 3-manifold.  Meaning, with the Riemann metric it inherits from $\mathbb R^4$, it is flat.

I believe the question of which *compact* Euclidean 3-manifolds embed in $\mathbb R^4$ was settled by Crisp and Hillman.  The answer is only $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ and the bundle over $S^1$ whose fibre is $S^1 \times S^1$ with the monodromy (of order two) acting by rotation by $\pi$ on the torus $S^1 \times S^1$.

- J. Crisp, J. Hillman, Embedding Seifert fibred 3-manifolds and $Sol^3$-manifolds in 4-space, Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) (1998) no. 3 685--710.

Of course, these are simply smooth embeddings.  I do not know whether or not you can position these manifolds so that they inherit a flat metric from a particular embedding.  I suspect you can't find such positions but off the top of my head I don't have a proof.

Comment: @Ryan: Great! "Euclidean 3-manifold" is a useful keyphrase, new to me.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: First, as in comment above, see [When is a Riemannian metric equivalent to the flat metric on $\mathbb R^n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8023/when-is-a-riemannian-metric-equivalent-to-the-flat-metric-on-mathbb-rn/8026#8026)

Getting there. What you want is Ricci flat 3-manifolds in $\mathbb R^4.$ Plus you want to write this in terms of the second fundamental form. So, what you are looking for is at least two out of three principal curvatures equal to 0. I found this nice three page item by Hicks, [LINK](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-03/S0002-9939-1965-0176483-0/S0002-9939-1965-0176483-0.pdf), what you have is the case $n=3$ in Corollary 6. The terminology of Hicks is not up to date necessarily.

As I commented, you would like a book for undergraduates by John A. Thorpe called *Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry*. His whole point is to write everything for hypersurfaces of $\mathbb R^{n+1}.$ Given your work in discrete geometry, I think this viewpoint will always be useful to you.

This is also an exercise on the final page in Unit 12 of [LINK](http://www.cs.elte.hu/geometry/csikos/dif/dif.html)
Exercise 12-3. Express the Ricci curvature of a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ in a
principal direction in terms of the principal curvatures.

Comment: Thanks, Will, I just ordered the Thorpe book. For the record, Hick's _Cor.6_: "A hypersurface is Ricci flat if and only if it is Einstein with total curvature zero. If $n=3$ and $M$ is Ricci flat, then the second mean curvature is also zero so at points $m$ on $M$ that are not flat points ($L_m \neq 0$), the multiplicity of the nonzero principle curvature is unity."

Comment: For 3-manifolds the Riemann curvature tensor is recoverable from the Ricci tensor, so "Ricci flat" implies its a Euclidean manifold -- locally isometric to open subsets of $\mathbb R^3$.  

Comment: @Ryan: Great!  Terminological variations are converging...

Answer (score 2):

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00025-023-01982-8), I showed that an open and dense subset of any flat ruled submanifold (and, in particular, of any flat hypersurface without planar points) is a union of cylindrical, conical, and tangent submanifolds, as defined by Definitions 1.2–1.4. A partial converse also holds.

The proof hinges on the fact that, under reasonable assumptions, the singularities of a ruled submanifold always concentrate
along a lower dimensional "striction" submanifold, exactly as in the classical two-dimensional case.